# Why did Grima opt for this solution to her problems?

Tags: katla

On the show *Katla*, Grima appears to struggle with the fact that

> her recently arrived meteorite double

wants to live her life, do her job, have her husband, redecorate her house, and so forth.

To resolve this conundrum,

> the original Grima decides that a good old-fashioned game of Russian roulette is only fair solution.

Not, say, splitting the work, or flipping a coin to see who had to start a new life. The two play, and one of them dies (probably the original).

It is probably not a surprise that the meteorite version of her also thought this was a good idea, since, after all, they are mostly the same person. What is less clear is why *either* of them were on board, since, as far as I can tell, the show does *not* show her to have any suicidal ideations before this point, and it seems as if they are less interested in dying than in having a "fair" resolution to their conflict.

Why did Grima think that Russian roulette was the best way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Shouldn't "*Not, say …*" be in the spoiler box too?

Comment: "Dies"?  Based on the aim, I'd say it was only a few lost teeth, badly damaged palate, loss of nose, and generally mutilated face.

Comment: @RayButter - Huh? That sounds likely to cause death from blood loss in any case.

Comment: Random anecdotal tidbit: My first thought after watching that scene: "Now they'll have to redo the living room after all."

Comment: My above comment notwithstanding, excellent question - I was absolutely pondering to ask just this, but couldn't decide how to frame the question yet. I was indeed quite astonished, maybe even alienated, by the depicted course of action, as up until that point, Grima was not exactly trying to keep the other person a secret. What is more, she seemed actually interested in finding out what it's all about.

Comment: @RayButterworth: Well, we see the remains buried outside the house in one of the last scenes of the episode. It can safely be said that one of them died.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, my comment was about the directing, not the plot. The actor held the gun in a position that would cause serious injury and mutilation, but the bullet would not have gone anywhere near the brain: head tipped back, barrel under chin, bullet through gun's muzzle and then through human's muzzle. Occasionally, people are stupid enough to actually do this. E.g. see [Does shooting from under your chin actually kill you without hurting? - Quora](https://qr.ae/pGOKpN).